# How to obtain the Object Manager in Unit-Tests?

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, object-manager

I've created the second unit-test for my second class. The second class will take a dependency of a first class instance and in one test I'd like to use the object manager to create the second class.

How do I manage that my unit-test gets the object manager injected in Magento 2 so that I can use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use in your unit test an instance of `\Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager`.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager
 */
protected $objectManager;
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    ....//your mocks go here
    $this->objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
}
```

Then you can use this object manager to instantiate your other class:

```
$this->objectManager->getObject('Your\Other\Class\Here');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius for the fast reply. It does not inject, but obtains it from state: `$subject = (new ObjectManager($this))->getObject(ConfiguredFile::class);` - works in my case.