# Object Manager in Unit Testing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-community, phpunit

I am trying to write UnitTests for my module for magento 2.

For this purpose i need access to the objectManager->create method.

i already tried what Marius suggested here: [How to obtain the Object Manager in Unit-Tests?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96192/how-to-obtain-the-object-manager-in-unit-tests)

but if i run those unittest, i get the following error message:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager::create()

am I doing anything wrong?

I searched through the magento core code, but I wasn't able to get the "real" objectManager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object manager for unit tests is in `magento/framework/TestFramework/Unit/Helper/ObjectManager.php` and you obviously instantiated it, otherwise you would not get this error message. But you are using it wrong, it does not have a `create()` method. As explained in the linked answer, you need `getObject()`:

```
public function getObject($className, array $arguments = [])
```

> I am using the ObjectManager::create method to get an Instance of my Helper class in another custom class. So i shouldnt use ~::create at all?

Not with this object manager helper for unit tests. It has a different interface than the regular object manager. It sounds like you are passing the unit test object manager to a class under test. This is not how it is intended to be used.

In an integration test you can use: `Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager::getInstance()` which works like the "real" object manager. In a unit test, you could instantiate or mock the real object manager `Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager`.

But the fact that you need it, tells you that there's something wrong. Don't use the object manager to get an instance of your helper. Instead, add your helper as a constructor parameter and let Magento handle the Dependency Injection.

Comment: I am using the ObjectManager::create method to get an Instance of my Helper class in another custom class. So i shouldnt use  ~::create at all?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that using the objectManager there is totally wrong, even if it works :)